# Unresolved reference: rememberNavController in jetpack compose

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose, navcontroller

I am trying to implement navigation in jetpack compose but I have added the following dependency as described in google docs

`implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.3"`

but I am getting the error `Unresolved reference: rememberNavController`while in the next line which is to implement navController

```
@Composable
fun NavigationComposable(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()
}
```

Here is the dependency in the gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.littlePro'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.littlePro"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {


    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.3"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
}
```

I have also tried to import some dependencies in the composable file like

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.navigation.NavDestination
import androidx.navigation.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController

@Composable
fun NavigationComposable(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()
}
```

but it gives the error `Unresolved reference: navigation`.

Answer (score 1):

This one seems to be missing from your imports:

```
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
```

If this doesn't help then try:

```
Build-> Clean Project
```

and then,

```
Build-> Rebuild Project
```

Also, you can try `File->Invalidate Caches-> Check 1st and 2nd-> Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: I did as you suggested but unfortunately the error is still the same. In the import statement, the error is over the "navigation" saying `Unresolved reference: navigation`

Comment: Is it multi-module project?

Comment: Can you share other dependencies of your project? Like compose version and all. Also, have you added compose_bom?

Comment: I have added the dependencies above. I am just starting this project, it only has a file of MainActivity in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
val nav_version = "2.7.6"
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version")
```

This works for me. You can try using version catalog as I am using that. Also, check your gradle version, maybe that's an issue. I am using gradle DSL for managing dependencies. Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

I have had some issues with 2.7.3, try downgrading to 2.5.0 and see if that helps

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.0"
```

Comment: I have tried it but it is giving the same error.